# identify and quantify cluster types in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following graph:

[image]

That's made from the given data:

```
K01 <- cbind(c(1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14),
         c(2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 10, 12, 14, 15))
K02 <- graph_from_edgelist(K01, directed = FALSE)
```

I'd like to be able to quantify the number and type of all subclusters in the graph. So I'd like to be able to be able separate clusters of the same size by whether they're circular or not, or other properties about the nodes.

I can get cluster size pretty easily with:

```
K03 <- components(K02)
K04 <- groups(K03)
```

But this doesn't help me sort by cluster structure.

Comment: @d.b that only returns the number of groups within the graph? I'm looking for something that helps me discern that even though there are 3 clusters of size 3, there are two different cluster structures.

Comment: @d.b sorry I substituted length for lengths, but the problem is still the same, I can already get the number of nodes each cluster contains.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure but it seems like as long as there are no [loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)), if the number of edges in a group is equal to or greater than the number of vertex, it is circular.

```
with(do.call(rbind, lapply(K04, function(x){
    g = induced_subgraph(K02, x)
    data.frame(n = vcount(g),
               type = ifelse(ecount(g) >= vcount(g), "circular", "simple"))
})), table(n, type))
#   type
#n   simple circular
#  2      3        0
#  3      2        1
```

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to d.b for his help on this. I broke down and wrote a function that I think performs the task I was trying to accomplish. It's a bit verbose and probably clunky, but it seems to work for what i need it to.

```
######
# take an igraph graph
# and return a nested list the length of the number of unique cluster structures
# where each list item is a list of clusters that shared that structure
# names ?
######

CategorizeSubGraphs <- function(IGraph) {

  cat("\n")
  # get groups
  IGroups <- groups(components(IGraph))

  Structures <- vector("list",
                       length = length(IGroups))
  StructNames <- vector("list",
                        length = length(IGroups))
  AllSubGraphs <- vector("list",
                         length = length(IGroups))

  # initialize a progress bar
  pBar <- txtProgressBar(style = 1L)

  # Get all graph structures, remove names for unique()
  for (i in seq_along(Structures)) {
    AllSubGraphs[[i]] <- induced_subgraph(graph = IGraph,
                                         vids = IGroups[[i]])
    Structures[[i]] <- AllSubGraphs[[i]][seq(length(AllSubGraphs[[i]][1]))]
    StructNames[[i]] <- dimnames(Structures[[i]])[[1]]
    dimnames(Structures[[i]]) <- list(NULL,
                                      NULL)
    setTxtProgressBar(pb = pBar,
                      value = i / length(Structures))
  }
  cat("\n")
  # categorize by structure
  GraphSizes <- sapply(unique(Structures),
                       function(x) nrow(x))
  AllSizes <- sapply(Structures,
                     function(x) nrow(x))
  GraphTemplates <- unique(Structures)

  Result <- vector("list",
                   length = length(GraphTemplates))
  StructureCategory <- vector("integer",
                              length = length(AllSizes))
  # assign each subgraph to a category
  for (i in seq_along(StructureCategory)) {
    Catch <- which(GraphSizes == AllSizes[i])
    if (length(Catch) == 1L) {
      StructureCategory[i] <- Catch
    } else {
      for (j in seq_along(Catch)) {
        if (all(GraphTemplates[[Catch[j]]] == Structures[[i]])) {
          StructureCategory[i] <- Catch[j]
        }
      }
    }
    setTxtProgressBar(pb = pBar,
                      value = i / length(StructureCategory))
  }

  Count <- rep(0L,
               length(Result))

  ResultSizes <- sapply(unique(StructureCategory),
                        function(x) length(which(StructureCategory == x)))

  for (i in seq_along(Result)) {
    Result[[i]] <- vector("list",
                          length = ResultSizes[i])
  }

  # collect all subgraphs into their distinct categories

  for (i in seq_along(StructureCategory)) {
    Count[StructureCategory[i]] <- Count[StructureCategory[i]] + 1L
    Result[[StructureCategory[i]]][[Count[StructureCategory[i]]]] <- AllSubGraphs[[i]]
  }
  cat("\n")
  return(Result)
}
```

So this tries to, and I think successfully sorts and summarizes all the subgraphs in a given graph.

So given:

```
K01 <- cbind(c(1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 16, 18, 18, 17, 20, 21, 21),
             c(2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 10, 12, 14, 15, 18, 17, 19, 16, 21, 22, 23))
K02 <- graph_from_edgelist(K01,
                           directed = FALSE)
```

Which starts with:

[image]

```
K03 <- CategorizeSubGraphs(IGraph = K02)
length(K03) # the number of distinct subgraph types
[1] 5
lengths(K03) # the number of individual subgraphs for each type
[1] 3 2 1 1 1
```

And you can plot the individual subclusters/subclusters out appropriately, and grab their names from the graph object.

I've not tested this with graphs with interconnected subgraphs, because I need it with a fairly specific type of data, but it's here if anyone else has this question!